Build systems can't find references when library is built in another project, why?
So I have a library that compiles when compiled by itself using its CMake. I then include this library as a git submodule in another project, and now it fails to find references in the code for some reason.
/usr/bin/ld: libfreedom/libfreedom.so: undefined reference to `drmModeGetResources'
/usr/bin/ld: libfreedom/libfreedom.so: undefined reference to `drmModeGetConnector'
/usr/bin/ld: libfreedom/libfreedom.so: undefined reference to `drmModeFreeConnector'

This is the CMakeLists.txt for the library that builds by itself:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(libfreedom LANGUAGES C)

# Specify the C standard
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# Add library target
add_library(libfreedom SHARED src/libfreedom.c)

target_include_directories(libfreedom PRIVATE /usr/include/libdrm)

# Prevent it from being called liblibfreedom.so
set_target_properties(libfreedom PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "freedom"  # This will create libfreedom.so
)

# Install targets and configuration
install(TARGETS libfreedom DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES include/libfreedom.h DESTINATION include)

And this is the CMakeLists.txt for the project. Note that cmake works but then while trying to use make or ninja I get the error messages above.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Freedom)

# Add the submodule as a dependency
add_subdirectory(libfreedom)

# Create the executable
add_executable(Freedom src/main.c)

# Link the submodule library to the main project
target_link_libraries(Freedom PRIVATE libfreedom)

target_include_directories(Freedom PRIVATE libfreedom/include)


Try changing PRIVATE to PUBLIC in target_include_directories(libfreedom PRIVATE /usr/include/libdrm).
I found this:
Target command scope in CMake

Unfortunately, that didn't work

You were actually semi-right I think since that was one of the steps (I think) I had to take to get the correct solution. Thanks :)

A shared library can be linked successfully while containing any number of undefined references.
It is normal to link a shared library in this way. You don't have to link it against its (shared library)
dependencies. But a program cannot be linked containing undefined references (unless you coerce
the linker to tolerate them). Therefore when you link a program against a shared library,
the undefined references in the shared library must be resolved in the program by also linking the dependencies of the shared library that define them.
Example:
Sources:
$ cat foo.c
extern void bar();

void foo(void)
{
    bar();
}

$ cat bar.c
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

$ cat main.c
extern void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}

Compile the sources:
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gcc -c -fPIC foo.c bar.c

Link two shared libraries:
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so bar.o

Both of them linked without error despite containing undefined references:
$ nm --undefined-only libfoo.so
                 U bar
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
$ nm --undefined-only libbar.so                 w 
                 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U puts@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 

which include the undefined reference to bar in libfoo.so and the undefined
reference to puts in libbar.so. The latter will be resolved in program linkage by the automatic linking of the C runtime library, libc.
Now attempt to link a program using main.o and libfoo.so but not libbar.so:
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
/usr/bin/ld: ./libfoo.so: undefined reference to `bar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

We need to add libbar.so to the program linkage because libfoo.so imposes that
dependency on the program.
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo -lbar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)

That is now successful:
$ ./prog
bar

In your case, libfreedom evidently depends on libdrm, so you should add libdrm
to the linkage of program Freedom. (You could alternatively add it to the linkage of
libfreedom, but libdrm is a public library that is presumably installed in one of your linker's
default search directories, so it would usually be put it in the linkage of a program
that depends on it, directly or indirectly).

I get that I need to link the library, I just don't see how my CMakeLists.txt doesn't and why it's fine when I built the library alone but not in the project

My previous answer was wrong, I believe the correct solution is this (but I could be wrong again). The solution I think is adding the -ldrm flag to the target_link_libraries statement. This makes the build tool search the include paths provided by libfreedom (by using the PUBLIC specifier in the target_include_directories statement) for drm.h.
My Project:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(freedom)

# Add the submodule as a dependency
add_subdirectory(libfreedom)

# Create the executable
add_executable(freedom src/main.c)

# Link the submodule library to the main project as a shared library
target_link_libraries(freedom PUBLIC libfreedom -ldrm)

My library:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(libfreedom LANGUAGES C)

# Specify the C standard
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# Add library target
add_library(libfreedom SHARED src/libfreedom.c)

target_include_directories(libfreedom PUBLIC
    /usr/include/libdrm
    include/
)

# Prevent it from being called liblibfreedom.so
set_target_properties(libfreedom PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "freedom"  # This will create libfreedom.so
)

# Install targets and configuration
install(TARGETS libfreedom DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES include/libfreedom.h DESTINATION include)

